# Python: How can I append literal bytes to a string with no decoding?

Tags: python, character-encoding

In Python, a string can have arbitrary bytes, via `"\x??"` escaping.  These bytes don't necessarily have to map to a char in an encoding.  For example, we can have `"\xa0"`, even though 0xa0 isn't a good utf-8 char.

However, if I have a byte array, such as `b'\xa0'`, I can't append it to a string without decoding it.  What if I want to just append literally, just like `"\xa0"`?

How can I append a series of bytes to a string without decoding them at all, just like `"\x"` escape chars? Is there a "literal decoding" or "no decoding" option to `decode()`? If not, is there another way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need to end up with a string? Can you just keep all the data in a `bytearray`?

Comment: Try "latin1" when decoding.

Comment: Python internally stores strings as Unicode, so it needs to be able to convert what you're adding to a Unicode code point.

Comment: It seems awfully like what a `bytes` object would do

Comment: I agree with @SuperStormer.  `latin1` is probably what you want.  It is a one-to-one conversion of bytes to characters with the identical value.

Comment: Sounds like an xy problem to me. What do you want to do with the string (which it no longer is) once you have appended all those bytes? You might have to encode the string to a bytes objects before appending bytes to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider whether storing these in a string is truly the best for your usecase. Storing as bytes/bytesarray is usually the more idiomatic option.

However, if you have considered this and still decided to proceed, then you should pass `"latin1"` as the encoding option to `bytes.decode`. This  converts the bytes directly to the characters with the corresponding value.

Comment: Thanks.  This is not for internal use, but for a case where I need a string object with particular bytes.  I tested and `latin1` works as you describe, but could not find this in Python docs (or docs for the charset in general).  Can you point me to a reference?